# FileStream in app cannot access file locked by service despite FileShare.Read option

Tags: c#, winforms, service, io

If I've understood the `FileMode` and `FileAccess` options correctly, we should be able to use them to specify one `FileStream` as Read/Write and grant a second Read access to see current contents. However when these run separately across the user/service boundary we are getting an `IOException`.

We have a simple setup where a C# service runs and generates a text-based log file, and we have a WinForms app which attempts to "open/read/close" (on button click) the same log file in order to display (a snapshot of) its contents.

The C# service opens a `FileStream` on startup, and keeps it open for the lifetime of the service:

```
_serviceLogLock = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read);
```

The non-service (WinForms) application then attempts to open the same file purely to read the contents:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```

This triggers

> IOException: "The process cannot access the file 'xxx' because it is being used by another process".

Given the service explicitly opens the file using the `FileShare.Read` option I would expect the WinForms app to have the read access it is asking for.

Comment: Try `using (var file = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,, FileShare.ReadWrite))
{}` rather than using `FileStream`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the non-service application, it also needs the `FileShare.ReadWrite` parameter, resulting:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

The problem you're having isn't that the service isn't allowing the non-service application to open the file, but that your non-service application tries to read the file, declaring that it cannot be read/written/deleted by other processes at the same, when some other process already has it open.

Comment: We'd already tried adding FileShare.Read but we needed FileShare.ReadWrite. Your explanation makes sense and worked. Thank you.